# $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{2}+4^{2}+\ldots+(2 n)^{2}}{(2 n)^{3}}=?$

Tags: calculus, limits

Solve :
$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{2}+4^{2}+\ldots+(2 n)^{2}}{(2 n)^{3}}=?$$

---

Can I say : ($ n^2 \ll n^3 )$ So We have :

$$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^{2}+4^{2}+\ldots+(2 n)^{2}}{(2 n)^{3}}=0$$

Comment: Nope  what you say is not true it is easy to see that it is a basic problem that could be handled using either limits or by using limit of a infinite sum

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824803/sum-of-the-square-of-natural-numbers-mathematical-proof

Comment: Your logic would work except that there are $n$ terms in the sum.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $$\begin{align*} 2^2+4^2 + \cdots + (2n)^2 & = 2^2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2. \\ & = \frac {2} {3} n(n+1) (2n+1). \end{align*}$$ So $$\begin{align} \frac {2^2+4^2 + \cdots + (2n)^2} {(2n)^3}  & = \frac {1} {12} \left ( 1 + \frac 1 n \right ) \left (2 + \frac 1 n \right ) \\ & \rightarrow \frac {1} {12} \times 1 \times 2 \\& = \frac 1 6 \end{align}$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is Riemann sums; we want $$\frac12\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2=\frac12\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$2^2+4^2+...+(2n)^2=2^2\left[1+2^2+3^2+...+n^2\right]=4\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

The sum of powers can be calculated be [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Alternatively, you can use the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) which will imply

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{2^2+4^2+...+(2n)^2}{(2n)^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(2(n+1))^2}{(2(n+1))^3-(2n)^3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The limit can be rewritten as follows:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} (2i)^2}{(2n)^3}=4\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} i^2}{(2n)^3}$$

Since:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2\sim \int_{0}^{n} i^2 di\sim\frac{n^3}{3}  \ \ \ \ n \to \infty $$

Then the limit becomes:

$$4\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{n^3}{3}}{8n^3}=\frac 16$$

:)